# linux if / elif / fi command

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, sh

I have a question.  If my `if` statement is `true`, does it skip the `elif` check and goes straight to `fi` or does it still check the `elif` statements?

Example of the script :

```
if [ argument1 || argument2 ]  
     then  
          do something.  
elif [ argument2 || argument3 ]  
     then  
          do something.  
elif [ argument2 || argument4 ]  
     then  
          do somthing.  
else  
          do somthing else.  
fi
```

My question being that I would want my `elif` statements to still be checked if my first `if` statement was true.  I would also want my `elif` statements to be checked if my first `elif` statement was `true`... etc.  Basically I would want all my `if` and `elif` statements to all be checked.

NB. I realize I could change all of my `elif` to `if` statements and this would probably resolve my issue since all `if` statements would get checked.  But this question is also out of curiosity and better knowledge of the `if` and `elif` statements.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: The whole point of else if is this. You can use just if to execute all true commands

Comment: `[ condition || condition ]` is not valid, you need to use `[[`. `[[ condition || condition ]]`, otherwise, `[ condition ] || [ condition ]`.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you, I realized this while doing some script testing.  :)

Answer (score 4):

The `elif` statement is not checked if one of the prior ones matched. `elif` is short for "else if"; it means that you should check this other condition if the previous one did not match.

As you say, you can just use multiple `if` statements for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Once a condition is met, the `if` statement terminates and the remaining `elif` conditions will not be checked.

Example:

```
if echo foo
then
   echo "in foo"
elif echo bar
then
   echo "in bar"
fi
```

prints

```
foo
in foo
```

If you want them all checked, then you need to break it into multiple if-statements as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that this is an old post, for what the OP had originally asked about would be better served with a case/esac statement from BASH >=4.0 with the `;;&` terminator.  And, since [BASH 4.0 was released 20 Feb 2009](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html#NCTERM), they should be able to use it in that script.

Something like this:

```sh
    case $anyargument in
        [[ argument1 || argument2 ]] )
            do something
            ;;&
        [[ argument2 || argument3 ]] )
            do something
            ;;&
        [[ argument2 || argument4 ]] )
            do something
            ;;
        * ) 
            do something else.
            ;;
    esac
```

Now, I used the regular `;;` terminator at the last actual test so it wouldn't fall through to the catch-all (READ: `else`) statement.  But the way that is written, all the tests will be checked and if they resolve `true`, the code will be executed.

Hope that will be useful.